# Why is there only one preview when there are actually 2 (JavaScript, Screen-casting/Camera recording simultaneously)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a quiz (as you may gather from my previous posts), and I've come acre this problem: I need two previews for a camera and the screen-recording to come up, but I only get one preview. Can anybody explain why this is happening? 
Also, is there a way to completely remove the previews and instead save the streams to a video file?

```
<p><button id="start">Start Capture</button> 
<br><button id="stop">Stop Capture</button></p>
<video id="screen" autoplay></video>   
<video id="camera" autoplay></video>  
<pre id="log" style="display: none;"></pre> 
      
<script>
const screenElem = document.getElementById("screen");
const cameraElem = document.getElementById("camera");
const logElem = document.getElementById("log");
const startElem = document.getElementById("start");
const stopElem = document.getElementById("stop");

// Options for getDisplayMedia()

var displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "always"
  },
  audio: false
};


// Set event listeners for the start and stop buttons
startElem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  startCapture1();
  startCapture2();
}, false);

stopElem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stopCapture();
}, false); 

console.log = msg => logElem.innerHTML += `${msg}<br>`;
console.error = msg => logElem.innerHTML += `<span class="error">${msg}</span><br>`;
console.warn = msg => logElem.innerHTML += `<span class="warn">${msg}<span><br>`;
console.info = msg => logElem.innerHTML += `<span class="info">${msg}</span><br>`;

async function startCapture1() {
  logElem.innerHTML = "";
  try {
    cameraElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}
async function startCapture2() {
  try {
    screenElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }  
} 

function stopCapture(evt) {
    let tracksCam = cameraElem.srcObject.getTracks();
    let tracksScr = screenElem.srcObject.getTracks();
  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  cameraElem.srcObject = null;
  screenElem.srcObject = null;
} function dumpOptionsInfo() {
  const cameraTrack = cameraElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
  const screenTrack = screenElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0]; 
  console.info("(Camera)Track settings:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(cameraTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
  console.info("(Camera)Track constraints:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(cameraTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
  console.info("(Screen)Track settings:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(screenTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
  console.info("(Screen)Track constraints:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(screenTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}
            </script>
```

***Thanks for any help!***

Comment: There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).